# Add the day (Monday, Tuesday, etc) to input from MaterializeCSS

Tags: javascript, materialize

I want to add the `"day" (Monday, Tuesday, etc)` to the input with the `datepicker`, but I don't know how can I do that.

I want something like this `"Tuesday 03 March, 2016"` instead of `"03 March, 2016"`
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify date format when creating datepicker.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true,
        selectYears: 15,
        format: 'dddd d mmmm, yyyy'
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/9ck765q6/2/)

Comment: Thx a lot mate ! That's helped me :)